# Missing directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC" where is it? after VC 2010 Express Install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm running windows 8 X64 I with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.   I installed Visual c++ express and I am getting lib missing linker error when I look into the directory I see that the installation never install any libs, it didn't even create the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC directory..

I have also tried uninstalling, deleting the old C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10 directory and the reinstalling the vis2010 pro version even the ultimate. but still no libs created..   If I look into my previous Visual Studio 2012 installation I see that C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\Lib is there but no mater what I do I can't get my visual studio 2010 install to install the libs I need

Please help.   Itsw driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1):

Please check the installation Drive of your Visual Studio 2010. you might have installed in D drive and VC and its sub folder might exist in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10/VC....

Answer (score 0):

This folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" is installed by visual studio 2012.

Comment: what about folder 11.0?? Does that come through the Update 4?